# Can't upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10 /boot folder too small according to installer

Tags: boot, upgrade, 17.10

I'm trying to update from 17.04 to 17.10.  Using any of the distribution update commands, I get the start of the 17.10 installation, but the update aborts as I need 167 M in my 243 MiB /boot partition. I need 1,756 K of additional space.  I've removed all images except my 4.10.0-37 current image.  I've autoremoved and I've changed my COMPRESS=xz as suggested by the installer.  My current image still takes up 66758 leaving only 161773 (70%) free. I've tried to see about making my boot folder larger with GParted, but it won't let me make it any larger.

Comment: Having the exactly same issue, posted [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967405/cannot-update-to-17-10-not-enough-free-space-on-boot) which pretty much duplicates this one (before noticing it).

Comment: Can you just copy /boot partition under / partition, then nuke /boot partition and forget the whole nightmare? I've never created a separate /boot in the first place.

Comment: I'm a bit of a novice and not confident with nuking the /boot partition. I used LVM to format my ssd and rotating media.  I partitioned the drives as suggested by the default.  Didn't know any better.

Comment: Moving boot files can cause grub to fail. It is fixable. Will  gparted allow you to unmount the /boot partition?

Comment: I looked at the /boot folder in GParted from a usb stick with Ubuntu and it said it was "not mounted".

Comment: Did no other changes, but I can now upgrade to 17.10